# How to set up a two column layout with javascript and django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a blog in django and I want to set the post as two column pages. I tried [CSS multicolumn](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp), however most navigators don't accept the option [column-fill](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-fill.asp) that allows to fill the columns unevenly.

I'm looking for a way to do it using javascript (or jquery), any idea???

This is the css:

```
.double-column{
  -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto; /* Firefox */
  column-fill: auto;
  max-height: 1133px;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that you've tried already.

Comment: I just added the css. There is nothing like `-webkit-column-fill: auto;` for other browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [columnizer library](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) for jquery. It's very easy to use and allows different number of columns, settings for different pages, options to locate images, etc.

An example [here](http://welcome.totheinter.net/autocolumn/sample10.html)